# Attribute {StaticResource resourcename} value is out of range

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources

I have a button in a page defined as:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource resourcename}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Height="32" >
```

and the resource "resourcename" is defined in the app as follow:

```
        <Grid x:Key="resourcename">
            <Path Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Data="M7.99799,14.26781 .....
        </Grid>

</Application.Resources>
```

When the application starts the following exception is raised:

**Attribute {StaticResource resourcename} value is out of range.**

I can't understand why, and BTW into the designer I can see the path correctly displayed. What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen people trying to and complaining about Content being set from a `UIElement` stored in a resources collection. I would refrain from that approach - one problem being - a `UIElement` might only be a child of a single `UIElement`. A better approach might be to store a `DataTemplate` in resources and set that `DataTemplate` as a button's `ContentTemplate`.